# How many Consensus algorithm does ethereum involve?

Tags: go-ethereum, cpp-ethereum

I know POW is the Consensus algorithm of ethereum now, and it will be changed to POS. But does ethereum has other Consensus algorithm besides POW and POS?
I heard from a man there are other Consensus algorithm in ethereum but I don't know if it is true. thank you .

Answer (score 2):

It would be nice to compile a list of available consensus algorithms. I marked this answer as "community wiki", feel free to add to the list.

- Proof of Work (PoW) - currently in Mainnet
- Proof of Stake (PoS) - currently in research
- Proof of Authority (PoA):

  - Clique - Geth, Parity and other clients [EIP-225](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/225)
  - AuRa (Authority Round) - Parity
- Raft - Quorum (Geth fork)
- IBFT (Istanbul BFT) - Quorum (Geth fork)
- IBFT 2.0 - Pantheon (Java Ethereum client)
- ...append here...

Answer (score -1):

list available here official & ...

CORE list 
https://eips.ethereum.org/core

other project:
https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Alternative-blockchains,-randomness,-economics,-and-other-research-topics